# how can I Implement this c# code in python

Tags: c#, python, registry, winreg

the following uses the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace from c# 
and implements the `unprotect` method from the `ProtectedData` class

```
byte[] output = ProtectedData.Unprotect(input, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

I'm trying to access my pc's HKEY_LOCALMACHINE registry with python because theres a key somewhere in it that i need (to read), in order to decrypt a file.
I read the docs but I'm still just not sure what method I should use for that purpose

```
aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
```

I'm not quite sure what comes next so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata

```
import win32crypt

#open binary file in readmode
filecontents = fileObject.read()


unecryptedFileContents = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(filecontents)
```